# ifdown bond0:0 takes down bond0 with it?

Tags: networking, rhel, bonding

I set up an interface alias on my bond0 interface with this file

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0:0
```

containing this

```
DEVICE=bond0:0
IPADDR=10.2.3.60
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

and when I

```
$ ifup bond0:0
```

it comes up fine and I can ping it.  However when I

```
$ ifdown bond0:0
```

it takes down both `bond0` and `bond0:0`

This seems like a bug, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.  How do I bring down `bond0:0` without taking down `bond0` with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you're using of assigning an alias IP address `bond0:0` is considered [deprecated at this point with Linux kernels](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/alias.txt).

```
IP-Aliasing:
============

IP-aliases are an obsolete way to manage multiple IP-addresses/masks
per interface. Newer tools such as iproute2 support multiple
address/prefixes per interface, but aliases are still supported
for backwards compatibility.

An alias is formed by adding a colon and a string when running ifconfig.
This string is usually numeric, but this is not a must.
```

The correct syntax for deleting/downing an alias is to use `ifconfig` like so:

```
$ ifconfig bond0:0 down
```

I suspect you'd be able to do the same with iproute2's `ip` command as well:

```
$ ip link set bond0:0 down
```

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I was not aware this had become obsolete.